# How could i create a buttons in a loop

Tags: python, button, pyqt4

i'm trying to create a simple table of buttons in a loop, but my code does not work. There is no errors, but i don't see result of execution.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

names = ['X+', 'X-', 'Y+',\
        'Y-', 'Z+', 'Z-',\
        'A1+', 'A1-', 'A2+',\
        'A2-', 'A3+', 'A3-',\
        'Hand']

pos = [(50, 100), (200, 100), (50, 200),\
        (200,200), (50, 300), (200,300),\
        (370, 100), (520, 100), (370, 200),\
        (520, 200), (370, 300), (520, 300),\
        (50, 400)]

size = [(74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (226, 74)]

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    ...........

    def createButtons(self):  
        index = 0
        self.buttons = []

        for i in names:
            self.buttons.append(index)
            self.buttons[index] = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
            self.buttons[index].setText(i)
            self.buttons[index].setGeometry(pos[index][0], pos[index][1], size[index][0], size[index][1])
            index += 1

def runApp():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    gui.createButtons()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

runApp()
```

Can you help me? 
names - a list of names,
pos - a list of position[x,y],
size - a list of w and h.

Comment: What is `namesVal`, where is it declared? Also you don't seem to be using the `i` within the for loop.

Comment: Sorry, i've changed name of list. names = namesVal and self.buttons[index].setText(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the size so you can see the buttons. You must use `resize()`

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

names = ['X+', 'X-', 'Y+',\
        'Y-', 'Z+', 'Z-',\
        'A1+', 'A1-', 'A2+',\
        'A2-', 'A3+', 'A3-',\
        'Hand']

pos = [(50, 100), (200, 100), (50, 200),\
        (200,200), (50, 300), (200,300),\
        (370, 100), (520, 100), (370, 200),\
        (520, 200), (370, 300), (520, 300),\
        (50, 400)]

size = [(74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (74, 74), (74, 74), (74, 74),\
        (226, 74)]

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def createButtons(self):  
        index = 0
        self.buttons = []

        for i in names:
            self.buttons.append(index)
            self.buttons[index] = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
            self.buttons[index].setText(i)
            self.buttons[index].setGeometry(pos[index][0], pos[index][1], size[index][0], size[index][1])
            index += 1

        self.resize(650, 500)

def runApp():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    gui.createButtons()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

runApp()
```

Screenshot:

[image]